# How to set height of v-select component - vuetify 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to properly set the height of the "v-select" component in vuetify version 3?

In the second version, prop height was used for this purpose:

`<v-select :items="..." height="30" />`

In version 3 this prop was removed

To give the height of the component, you need to add the height property to many different classes, I feel that this is not a good solution and maybe someone knows a better way

Answer (score 1):

You can use :deep CSS selector to overwrite Vuetify styles.
https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html

In your case it would be

`:deep(.v-field__input){ height: 100px; }`